# How to install "h3" library for H3 geospatial indexing system in R

Tags: r, spatial, uber-api, h3

My understanding is that the "H3 geospatial indexing system" is a kind of "coordinate system" developed by Uber, whose main feature is that it is based on a system of hierarchical hexagons. "he" is a library in R which could help one to work with data in this "H3 spatial reference system", but is not stored in CRAN but a GitHub (https://github.com/crazycapivara/h3-r).

However, I haven't been able to install this library in R. I have trayed this (as the instruction in the GitHub suggested):

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("crazycapivara/h3-r")
```

but it did not work, and is returning this message:

```
devtools::install_github("crazycapivara/h3-r")
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
 there is no package called ‘digest’
```

Then, I trayed the same steps but in "R-cloud" and get a different error:

```
h3_hex-ring.cpp:2:22: fatal error: h3/h3api.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/opt/R/4.0.3/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:181: recipe for target 'h3_hex-ring.o' failed
make: *** [h3_hex-ring.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘h3’
* removing ‘/home/rstudio-user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/h3’
Error: Failed to install 'h3' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpzwLngc/file1698ded56/h3_3.3.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I reviewed that GitHub, and I wasn't able to figure out what's wrong. Does anyone has successfully installed this library on R or knows a different library to work whit this kind of spatial reference system?

Comment: Did you follow the steps listed under "requirements" on the github readme page? If so, what was the output from those commands? To get past the error message about "digest" not available, try running `install.packages("digest")` yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is that you appear to need to install the dependency package 'digest' (and possibly others) before installing h3-r. Try doing that first (and I assume you were able to build the underlying C package as well).

I'm not sure how actively maintained `h3-r` is, so it may not play well with recent releases of R. If you want to try using H3 in R via the js transpile, try https://github.com/obrl-soil/h3jsr (disclaimer: I'm the author). It will likely struggle with very large datasets but should be ok for most smaller applications.